# jquery draggable/droppable as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a function so that i can have multiple drag/droppables in a page.
For that i made the following:

```
function apDrag(dragId,container) {
    $(function() {
          $('#'+dragId).draggable({ 
                revert: "invalid", 
                drag: function(e) {
                    var currentPos = $('#'+dragId).position();
                    $('#data').html('Left: '+currentPos.left+ ' Top: '+currentPos.top);
                }
            });
          $('#'+container).droppable({
            tolerance: 'fit',
            greedy: true,
            drop: function( event, ui ) {

                    // For some reason "dragId" defaults to "dragger2" here
                    // console.log(dragId); = dragger2; even though first function passes "dragger1" as dragId

                    $('#'+dragId).draggable({revert:"invalid"});
                    pos = $('#'+dragId).position();
                    cPosLeft = pos.left;
                    cPosTop = pos.top;
                    $('#data').html('Left: '+cPosLeft + ' Top: '+ cPosTop);
                    $('#'+dragId).html('ID: <b>'+dragId+'</b>');
                }
            });
      });
}
apDrag('dragger','container');
apDrag('dragger2','container');
```

The problem here is that for some reason the "dragId" being passed into the drop function of the droppable, always become the same, and are not "dragger1", "dragger2" as it should be. It always reverts to "dragger2" for both of the divs.

PS: The reason I am creating a droppable for each function is that they eventually will have different settings for each draggable.

Please see fiddle: [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravdqq2s/2/) for a better explanation

Comment: You are facing some closure issue. Anyway, to get the draggable element, use: `ui.draggable` which is a jq object. E.g: `pos = ui.draggable.position();`

Comment: Indeed that worked. Thank you.
Might i ask which closure issues you are referring to ?

Comment: In fact, you are setting droppable on same element twice, former options are overwritten and your document ready handler inside function is useless. Your code should be something like that instead: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravdqq2s/4/

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  A. Wolff, i found that using:

```
ui.draggable
```

in the drop function, i could get the correct id of the dragged div:

```
$('#'+container).droppable({
 tolerance: 'fit',
 greedy: true,
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
 var correctID = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
 // id of dragged element is now "correctID"
 }
});
```

A. Wolff also updated the fiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravdqq2s/4/)